# Invalid token error in Linkedin Gem when its work in CURL of Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

When i used CURL post from console then its work but when i used linkedin gem method in controller then its not working and get error regarding access token. Where is wrong here not findout.

## CURL Code

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"comment":"hello from google www.google.com! http://ibm.com","visibility":{"code":"anyone"}}'  https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?oauth2_access_token=AQVxxxxJXygzp_8Exxxxg7_7FaxxxxxxtWzBXAxxxxxa5z1MVK6-kubHJ5JIaGAxxxx234wndpAMc_CxmCsIHxxxxraleZqkU0t_WNEhxxxz8_cKpeOixxxxsd15-X-MdvzYVxxxx9hQ&format=json&title=linkedin HTTP/1.1
```

## LinkedIn gem code

```
      client = LinkedIn::Client.new(
      config[:your_consumer_key], 
      config[:your_consumer_secret] 
      )

      client.authorize_from_access(
      config[:oauth_user_token],
      config[:oauth_user_secret]
      )

      client.add_share(
      comment: 'Good Morning', 
      content: {'submitted-url' => 'http://www.github.com/blazeeboy' }
      )
```

Any one have a idea where is wrong here.

============= UPDATE =============

```
system 'curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "authToken: auth_token" --data '{"comment":"hello from google www.google.com! http://google.com","visibility":{"code":"anyone"}}' https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?oauth2_access_token=AQVxxxxygzp_8E3ySvg7_7FahixxxxxxtWzBXAja5OQ8a0wta5z1MVK6-kubHJ5JIxxxxwndpAMc_CxmCsIHxFlexxxxxleZqkU0t_WNxxxxmi7CMz8_cKpexxxx15-X-MdvzYVOxxxxm9hQ&format=json&title=linkedin HTTP/1.1'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "authToken: auth_token" --data '{}' https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares

Comment: Curl its work but when try to run from rails using CURL then issue in quote. Can you please check update part in question code where issue in single and double quote.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this :

```
system "curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'authToken: auth_token' --data '{'comment':'hello from google www.google.com! http://google.com','visibility':{'code':'anyone'}}' https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?oauth2_access_token=AQVxxxxygzp_8E3ySvg7_7FahixxxxxxtWzBXAja5OQ8a0wta5z1MVK6-kubHJ5JIxxxxwndpAMc_CxmCsIHxFlexxxxxleZqkU0t_WNxxxxmi7CMz8_cKpexxxx15-X-MdvzYVOxxxxm9hQ&format=json&title=linkedin HTTP/1.1"
```

In rails when you use double quotes inside single quotes it gives error with some commands.

OR you can try like this :

```
`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'authToken: auth_token' --data '{'comment':'hello from google www.google.com! http://google.com','visibility':{'code':'anyone'}}' https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?oauth2_access_token=AQVxxxxygzp_8E3ySvg7_7FahixxxxxxtWzBXAja5OQ8a0wta5z1MVK6-kubHJ5JIxxxxwndpAMc_CxmCsIHxFlexxxxxleZqkU0t_WNxxxxmi7CMz8_cKpexxxx15-X-MdvzYVOxxxxm9hQ&format=json&title=linkedin HTTP/1.1`
```